# Can QML drag-and-drop mechanic work without drag item moving?

Tags: drag-and-drop, qml, drag

I have a listview and a rectangle on top of it. The `ListView`'s delegates have `DropArea`s in them and the rectangle has drag enabled on Y axis with its relevant properties (hotspot, target).

When I move the rectangle up and down on the ListView, the `DropArea`s of the delegates are registering `onEntered` signals. Working as intended.

However, I am using `SmoothedAnimation` to scroll the list up and down when the rectangle is at the most top and bottom coordinates (`list.y = 0` and `list.height`). So the rectangle is not moving, and the `DropArea`s of the list's delegates are moving under it. In that case, the `onEntered` is not registered because there is no dragging, the rectangle is completely still and although its `hotspot` is entering and leaving the `DropArea`s, there is no interaction.

This is because dragging mechanic is sending events all the time when moving and any `DropArea`s it comes inside can register the event. In my case there is no dragging and therefore no events.

Question: Can drag events be manually activated? Can I somehow simulate drag?

Comment: Why do you need it to be a drag event? Wouldn't it be sufficient to call the function bound to `onEntered`, or are you really dependent on the event?

Comment: I need to know exactly when the rectangle has entered the drag areas of the list and the list is scrolling at various speeds.

Comment: Could you provide some code to play with, please?

Comment: Have you found a solution since?

Comment: Sorry, forgot about this issue in all of the work, posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to induce drag events by manually changing the `hotSpot` property of the rectangle above the list. QML Drag documentation says:

> Changes to hotSpot trigger a new drag move with the updated position.

So I have done this every time `Listview` `contentY` changes (vertical scrolling happens)

```
    onContentYChanged:
    {
        rectangle.Drag.hotSpot.x += 0.0001
        rectangle.Drag.hotSpot.x -= 0.0001
    }
```

In hindsight, however, this is a 'hacky' solution. `hotSpot` property is a `QPointF` class property ([link](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpointf.html)). This means it can be set using various methods (setX, setY, rx, ry..). For example, this:

```
rectangle.hotSpot += Qt.point(0,0)
```

or

```
rectangle.hotSpot = Qt.point(rectangle.hotSpot.x,rectangle.hotSpot.y)
```

should work in theory by resetting the `hotSpot` point when `contentY` changes, but testing revealed it unfortunately does not trigger a new drag move. (bug or intended, I don't know)

Now some of you that are more into Qt and QML might know more about this and how to properly adress the issue, but the above solution works for me and after testing everything I could imagine to get a cleaner solution, I settled on it.

Answer (score 2):

At first, you should change the `drag.target: parent` to `drag.target: this`. In this way instead of dragging the parent item, you drag only the mouseArea. After that, you should grab an image from the item that you want to drag. The code is here:

```
 Rectangle {
    id: rec
    width: 100
    height: 100
    
    Drag.active: dragArea.drag.active
    Drag.dragType: Drag.Automatic
    Drag.supportedActions: Qt.CopyAction
    
    MouseArea {
        id: dragArea
        anchors.fill: parent
        drag.target: this
        onPressed:{ 
            parent.grabToImage(function(result) {
                parent.Drag.imageSource = result.url
            })                  
            
        }
    }
}
```